# Potential memory leaks with Signal-R and Newtonsoft serialization

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

We are using Signal-R to synchronize an important (about 200MB) object (serialized using Newtonsoft) from one application to another. But every time the object is serialized and sent through Signal-R, the size of both applications increase drastically (about 200MB each time, what a surprise).

From our analysis, it seems that the memory is growing due to something within Signal-R.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: 200MB is a huge data, what is your network bandwidth?

Comment: it seems that network bandwidth is your main problem

Comment: Network bandwidth is not an issue. The problem is really the size of the application which is increasing each time the object is synchronized.